# PrototypeJS: How to get the position of an element having display: none?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I have a < ul > element, which is hidden using "display: none". I try to get the position of the element using

```
Element.cumulativeOffset(element);
```

That returns me nothing useful. Is there another way to get the position of such an element, or does it simply have no position?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of setting it to `display:none`, you could give it zero width and height, which will still allow you to calculate the offset.

Comment: Sounds like a plan, Ill try!

Answer (score 0):

Also of note `Element.cumulativeOffset(element)` returns an `Element.Offset` object not raw numbers. Try using `.toArray()` on the results of `Element.cumulativeOffset(element)`.

You can also call it like this `$('elementid').cumulativeOffset().toArray()`

[Element#cumulativeOffset](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Element/prototype/cumulativeOffset/)

Answer (score 0):

You could test to see if the element is hidden before doing these types of measurements, and if so, show the element, measure, and then hide it again. This will all be transparent to the user.